# radiobutton inside repeater always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I have a repeater with radiobuttons in it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#test input:radio").attr("name", "yourGroupName");
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<div id="test">
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep" onitemdatabound="rep_ItemDataBound" 
        onitemcommand="rep_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>   
<asp:RadioButton ID="n"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'  AccessKey='<%# Eval("id")%>' />   
</ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

I am using the javascript at the top to fix the radiobutton bug in .net. 
i bind a list to the repeater at page load, with a if `(!Page.IsPostback)` around it.
**edit:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rep.DataSource = z.Table.ToList();
            rep.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

then i have a button, that when clicked should do something with the radio button that's been selected, this is the problem now:

```
     foreach (RepeaterItem i in rep.Items)
        {
            RadioButton erb = i.FindControl("n") as RadioButton;
            if (erb.Checked)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
         }
```

no matter which radiobutton i select, when i click the button and i debug the entire loop, every checkbox == false. i'm doing more stuff with the code but i've simplified it, because this is the biggest problem.

i have seen countless of topics about this issue and i have looked through them all but i still can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Can you show us where you bind the repeater?

Comment: @JaneDoe try one thing Bind your repearter on every load, remove ispostback and check it

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using *RadioButtonList* instead of a repeater?  This makes it so the radio button *name* attributes are correct, and sets the *Checked* property correctly on callback.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding `OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"`  on you radio button this will trigger post back on click of the button and you will be able to find the Checked one

Comment: if i put autopostback = true on the radiobuttons the page just posts back and does nothing

Comment: So what do you get in the RadioButton1_OnCheckedChanged method does the break point hit inside it

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all down to the [sequence of events in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) .

Try putting your `DataBind` code in the `Page_Init` procedure, that way the state of the radiobuttons will be set by the time it reaches the `Page_Load` procedure.